# JQuery draggable and resizable images

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am having a few issues trying to get some basic jquery functionality working correctly.

I simply want to be able to drag an image (or multiple images) into a container and then resize them.

So far I have this

http://jsbin.com/ipoxe5/edit

The specific problems I am having are:

1) Can't get resize handles to display around the edge of the image

2) As soon as you click an image it 'jumps' directly into the containment div (#droppable) - You do not see any smooth drag animation, it just jumps directly to the div. I would like to actually have to 'drag' the image into the contasiment div rather than it auto jumping directly in as soon as you click an image.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: which browser?  I tested in chrome and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Firefox 4 - The image can br dragged into the containment div, but they just jump directly in when using firefox

Comment: Also - I just tested in chrome and it does exactly as I said above. No resize handles around the image when it is placed in the containment div and as soon as you click the image it jumps directly into the containment div - there is no smooth drag animation....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [containment](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment) option "Constrains dragging to within the bounds of the specified element or region."

If you want the images to be draggable, both inside and outside the dropzone, then you need to specify a container larger than just the droppable div.

Looking at the code for [resizable](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js), there is only code to add the visible handle on the lower right corner:

```
if ('se' == handle) {
        axis.addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se');
                };
```

So, it doesn't look like the visible handles are supported currently out of the box, you may need to add that functionality yourself.

Comment: But - I want the image to only be able to be moved within the containment div once they are dropped. So - to be able to drag the image into the div nice and smoothly - and once they are in there they can only be moved about within that div. I tried wrapping everything in another 'droppable' div but then it allowed me to drag the images back out of the smaller containment div after dropping them in....if that makes sense?

Comment: when initialising your draggable, you can set `revert:"invalid"`, so if you drag the image anywhere else, it pops back to its starting position. If you don't want the user to drag it back out, set `containment` in the droppables drop event: `drop: function(event,ui){ ui.draggable.draggable("option", "containment", "#droppable"); }`

Comment: Cheers DarthJDG - that's done it, any idea about the resize handles not showing??

Comment: @user734421 - I edited my answer to include information about the resize handles